# Action script for PHP form in Google App Engine not found

Tags: php, html, forms, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have the following directory structure:

```
/www
  - index.html
  - signUp.html
  - submitEmail.php
```

And then above this:

```
/www
app.yaml
```

Here's my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
script: www/\1

- url: /
static_files: www/index.html
upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
static_files: www/\1
upload: www/(.*)
```

When I click my submit form button I receive the following error:

```
No web page was found for the web address: https://<url>/submitEmail.php HTTP ERROR 404
```

Here's the form file:

```
<form class='email_form' action="/www/submitEmail.php" method="post">
            <input class='input_email' id='limitedInput' type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus>
            <br>
            <input type='text'>
</form>
```

I've been trying for hours to get this going but for some reason don't seem to be. Any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: Try `action="submitEmail.php"` in the form file

Comment: Still receiving the error. Is it something to do with my app.yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was incorrect handlers in `app.yaml`. This works:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
script: www/\1

- url: /
script: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
script: www/\1
```

I think the `static_file` declaration screwed up the web-server. Unfortunately not versed enough to explain exactly why but hopefully this leads people in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Hews, just to clarify what happens with the `static_file` filed. When you include this field, you're telling App Engine to serve the file as a resource that don't contain dynamic components, such as non dynamic HTML files, images, CSS etc. App Engine offers a separate set of servers dedicated to deliver static files that are optimized to handle request for static resources. That's why it didn't work for `submitEmail.php`.

Comment: Hey @dhauptman - I may have spoken prematurely. Having a set of other issues at the moment. Currently experiencing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479810/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-y9gg-t-string-suddenly-appearin?noredirect=1#comment95767903_54479810